# Laravel: Why isn't it stored in laravel storage

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

Why is it that when you upload the file it's not in the folder before you do `php artisan storage:link`  and it doesn't appear in the storage folder.

Coding in Controller:

```
$newName = '';
if ($request->file('image')) {
    $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $newName = $request->title.'-'.now()->timestamp.'.'.$extension;
    $request->file('image')->storeAs('cover', $newName);
}

$request['cover'] = $newName;
$book = Book::create($request->all());
```

And when  `dd($request->all());`

```
array:4 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\BookController.php:21
  "_token" => "QzxKNixPieDrq96s2TuMmGW2SwtJWMBUFZG2nvn7"
  "book_code" => "A001-16"
  "title" => "fefefe"
  "image" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#325 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "thumbnail_image001.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    ....
```

in View the from section has been given `<form action="book-add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and the input section has been given `<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" value="{{ old('image') }}">`.

What's wrong in my coding or something?